# Is direct attribute access more "pythonic" than a defined API

Tags: python

What's more "Pythonic"?

```
user.fullname = fullname
user.gender= gender
user.description = description
```

vs.

```
user.update_profile(fullname, gender, description)
```

Obviously, the latter is just a wrapper for the former in most cases (and my preference), but with all the talk I see online about how direct access (with property decorator) is more pythonic, I'm just curious.

Comment: python provides no mechanism for making data truly private .... thats just the way we roll

Answer (score 2):

Neither is more or less pythonic than the other; they have different use cases.

Use the former when you want to be able to update attributes one by one. Replace it with a property when the need arises. However, do use an explicit method when setting an attribute has side-effects beyond validation.

Use the latter when you must update all three attributes at once, e.g. when you need to do a sanity check on the combination of values. There's no special syntax that can reasonably replace this idiom.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you intend to use the class - I often find it useful to write theoretical usages of code before implementing it. For example, it's seems likely you'd use the User class like this:

```
user = User(fullname='Sally McExample', gender='F', description='...')
user.save()

# Later:
user = User.find(...)
user.fullname = 'Sally McChanged'
user.save()
```

Whereas with your proposed `update_profile` example, the same code would be tedious:

```
user = User.find(...)
user.update_profile('Sally McChanged', user.gender, user.description)
user.save()
```

Note that if you need to do more elaborate processing on the data than assignment (like value validation, or text-cleanup) you can turn the attribute into a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)... but if you foresee needing such behaviour from the start, then `update_profile`-type method makes it clearer more than assignment might happen

Comment: I think it would make more sense to have `.update_profile()` accept kwargs instead of args instead.  

`user.update_profile(fullname='Sally McChanged', description='lorem ipsum')`